# C# Crypto API examples

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm looking for examples + information on how to extract certificate information from the windows certificate store and perform operations like verifying signatures using the retrieved certificates. The API documentation for C# in this regard is quite poor, with many of the entries in msdn marked with "This language is not supported, or no code example is available.", I'm sorry I can't be more specific, I haven't done any programming using cryptographic api's. The particular certificate will be provided via a USB token. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the certificate store, you will want to look at the class called [`X509Store`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx). It will return instances of [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) that you can work with. You can also get instances of `X509Certificate2` from a file (the constructor that takes a string).
If you have access to the certificates' private key, you can use it to decrypt data by casting it to a [`DSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider_members.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was a real needle in a haystack!